# Problemas al ejecutar php artisan migrate

Tags: php, laravel, sql-server

estoy creando un proyecto en php laravel pero estoy cambiando gestor a sql pero estoy teniendo en problemas al ejecutar php artisan migrate y cuando lo ejecuto me sale este error:

```
 Illuminate\Database\QueryException 

  could not find driver (SQL: select * from sysobjects where type = 'U' and name = migrations)

  at C:\wamp64\www\ReportesMartinrea\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Database\Connection.php:678
    674▕         // If an exception occurs when attempting to run a query, we'll format the error
    675▕         // message to include the bindings with SQL, which will make this exception a
    676▕         // lot more helpful to the developer instead of just the database's errors.
    677▕         catch (Exception $e) {
  ➜ 678▕             throw new QueryException(
    679▕                 $query, $this->prepareBindings($bindings), $e
    680▕             );
    681▕         }
    682▕

  1   C:\wamp64\www\ReportesMartinrea\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Database\Connectors\Connector.php:70
      PDOException::("could not find driver")

  2   C:\wamp64\www\ReportesMartinrea\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Database\Connectors\Connector.php:70
      PDO::__construct("dblib:host=DESKTOP-GON88H8:1433;dbname=reportesmartinreaprueba;charset=utf8", "sa", "toribio12Q", [])
```

noce que mas me este faltando y estoy usando xamp y dentro de xamp en php.ini estoy colocando estas extenciones:

```
extension=php_pdo_sqlsrv_73_nts_x64.dll
extension=php_pdo_sqlsrv_73_ts_x64.dll
extension=php_sqlsrv_73_nts_x64.dll
extension=php_sqlsrv_73_ts_x64.dll
```

Comment: ¿estás usando sql server?

Comment: asi es estoy usando sql server

Comment: ¿Reiniciaste el servidor luego de agregar esas DDLs?

Comment: sip esque en teoria deberia ya haber funcionado pero noce que me este creando conflicto